# Configure default route on SCO Unix 5.0.5

Tags: unix

How do I configure a default route (or routes in general) on SCO Unix 5.0.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes are configured in `/usr/internet/etc/sco_ip/routes`. If this file doesn't exist, add as follows:

```
mkdir /usr/internet/etc/sco_ip
chmod 755 /usr/internet/etc/sco_ip
echo "net default 10.0.0.1" > /usr/internet/etc/sco_ip/routes
chmod 644 /usr/internet/etc/sco_ip/routes
```

To add the route dynamically:

```
route add -net default 10.0.0.1
```